# How do I create a matrix with an array or list in each entry in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a matrix to simulate an hospital time scheduled, but in each entry I need to save several values (patients). My question is, is it possible in R to make a matrix with an array or list in each position?

I need to create a 22x7 matrix filled with zeros and then I'll add pacients to each entry with a loop. Can I do it?

Comment: `a = matrix(list(list(0)),22,7)` creates a matrix of lists, `for (i in 1:prod(dim(a))) a[[i]] = list(1,2,3)` fills each element of the matrix (columnwise) with your desired Input.

Answer (score 0):

Example for a 2 by 2 matrix of list elements:

```
data = list(list(1, 2), list(2, 3), list(3, 4), list(4, 5))
m = matrix(data, 2, 2)

# get the list in position (1, 1):
m[1, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks, that should work ! And how do I access to the second position of my first list for example ? 

`m[2,1,1]`  ?

Comment: Stack indexes: `m[1, 1][[2]]`. Remember to use double brackets `[[` to get a list item.